# How to do algebraic division with R programming?

Tags: r

I've looked everywhere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374377/relational-algebra-division) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978533/how-to-understand-u-r%C3%B7s-the-division-operator-in-relational-algebra), but none of the answers match what I want. My question is like this.

what I want. My question is like this.

3xy : 2y

The answer I want is 3x/2

My attempt code is like this:

```
x <- 2/3
y <- x
cat("mark x:", x, "\n")
cat("mark y:", y, "\n")
```

Thank you, any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: What you are describing is pretty far afield of what R was built for. There are "computer algebra system" packages that will mimic this type of functionality (i.e. Ryacas package), but most people simply do not use R for this, rather something like Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

With **Ryacas** you can do:

```r
library(Ryacas)

yac_str("Simplify(3*x*y/(2*y))")
# "(3*x)/2"
```